# Next.js server component when converting to client component giving issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on a blog site with next.js. I have a home page which is a server component but now I wanted it to change to a client component so that I can make it interactive( integrate pagination).

But when I converted the code to client component, it started giving me issues such as browser window seems stuck from time to time with localhost opened. Also the api requests `getPosts` method is not storing by react's useState's setState function somehow strangely.

given below is the previous server component for the home page -

```
import { getCategoryPosts, getPosts } from '@/services'
import styles from '../../app/page.module.scss'
import PostCard from './PostCard'

type Props = { categorySlug?: string }

async function HomePagePosts({ categorySlug = '' }: Props) {
  const { postsContainer } = styles
  let posts
  if (!categorySlug) {
    posts = await getPosts()
  } else {
    posts = await getCategoryPosts(categorySlug)
  }

  return (
    <section className={postsContainer}>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <PostCard post={post} key={post.title}></PostCard>
      ))}
    </section>
  )
}

export default HomePagePosts
```

and below is the new client component -

```
'use client'

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getCategoryPosts, getPosts } from '@/services'
import styles from '../../app/page.module.scss'
import PostCard from './PostCard'

type Props = { categorySlug?: string }

function HomePagePosts({ categorySlug = '' }: Props) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function setAllPosts() {
      if (!categorySlug) {
        setPosts(await getPosts())
      } else {
        setPosts(await getCategoryPosts(categorySlug))
      }
    }
    setAllPosts()
  }, [])

  const { postsContainer } = styles

  return (
    <section className={postsContainer}>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <PostCard post={post} key={post.title}></PostCard>
      ))}
    </section>
  )
}

export default HomePagePosts
```

The above code is causing infinite loop resulting in window being stuck and also posts state is rendering to be empty and not updating.

Though if I console log the `getPosts()` method it gives me the correct content in return, so something is wrong with this conversion.

EDIT -

I have noticed something -

```
return (
    <section className={postsContainer}>
      help
      {posts?.map((post) => (
        <div key={post.title}>{post.title}</div>
        // <PostCard post={post} key={post.title}></PostCard>
      ))}
    </section>
  )
```

the above code gives the correct post.title content

but if I use the `<PostCard/>` component then only its keep loading and goes to infinite loop and do not show any content in posts state.

PostCard component is a server component which is an async functional compoenent, so can that be issue ?

Here is the PostCard code -

```
import { postsType } from '@/utils/types/types'
import styles from '../../app/page.module.scss'
import moment from 'moment'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { myPortfolioURL } from '@/services'
import LikeButton from '../buttons/LikeButton'
import CommentButton from '../buttons/CommentButton'

type Props = { post: postsType }

async function PostCard({ post }: Props) {
  const {
    postCard,
    postImage,
    title,
    summary,
    authorName,
    authorInfo,
    authorInfoContainer,
    authorImage,
    date,
    icon,
    userFeedbackContainer,
    leftAlign,
    rightAlign,
    readTimeContainer,
    postReactionSection,
  } = styles
  const authorId: string = (await myPortfolioURL(post.author.id)) || '/'
  return (
    <div className={postCard}>
      <div className={authorInfoContainer}>
        <Link
          href={authorId}
          className={authorInfo}
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <div className={authorImage}>
            <Image
              src={post.author.photo.url}
              style={{ objectFit: 'cover', borderRadius: '50%' }}
              sizes="(max-width: 768px) 40px, (max-width: 1200px) 50px, 40px"
              fill={true}
              alt={post.author.name}
            />
          </div>
          <p className={authorName}>{post.author.name}</p>
        </Link>

        <div className={date}>
          <p>{moment(post.createdAt).format('MMM DD, YYYY')}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Link href={`/post/${post.slug}`}>
        <div className={postImage}>
          <Image
            src={post.featuredImage.url}
            style={{ objectFit: 'cover', borderRadius: '.5rem' }}
            fill={true}
            alt={post.title}
          />
        </div>
      </Link>

      <h1>
        <Link href={`/post/${post.slug}`} className={title}>
          {post.title}
        </Link>
      </h1>
      <div className={summary}>{post.summary}</div>
      <div className={postReactionSection}>
        <div className={leftAlign}>
          <div className={userFeedbackContainer}>
            <LikeButton postId={post.id} />
            <CommentButton postId={post.id} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={rightAlign}>
          <div className={readTimeContainer}>{post.readTime} min read</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PostCard
```

Comment: Please share full code. including code for getPosts()

Comment: `setPosts(await getPosts())`  That shouldn't even work, as you have not marked the `useEffect` as been `async`  are you not getting a compiler error?

Comment: @Keith sorry for the partial code but I have just updated the code now it has async func but the issue remains the same

Answer (score 5):

You can not have async effect. Thus you need to do following

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getPosts().then(data => setPosts(data)); 
  }, [])
```

### Update:

As per the updated question. I notice that you are using Server component `PostCard` as a child of `client component`. This is the cause of the error. All children of client component are always client components.

Thus, you should remove server side code from the client component and also make it not async.

Comment: thanks for the help but its still not working!

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Also share your getPosts code

Comment: there is no error message, it just keep loading infinitely and also getPosts is working fine (actually I am using graphql so its code is pretty long). You can see my editted question I have updated some of my insights that the Child component is making some issue in this.

Comment: Please share your PostCard code

Comment: shared it on the editted part of the question

Comment: Updated the answer - basically you can not use server side code on client component or it's children

Comment: okay this seems to be promising, will try.